# Can't browse to Azure trafficmanager

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

Hi I have created a traffic manager which is pointing at an external domain (type Any) and it's status is online.

My problem is that when I browse to the website name.trafficmanager.net I get a 404 however the traffic manager is online with an endpoint configured properly.

The operation logs for my traffic manager are empty.Does anybody know what I can do to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: What is the CNAME setup for the domain name?

Comment: No cname at this stage just trying to browse directly to the trafficmanager.net DNS name generated for me when I created the traffic manager